# how to read and play a turn in music when it is inbetween 2 notes?

Tags: piano, notation, ornaments

for example in this Mozart piece, there is a turn in bar 7, and in bar 10

how are you suppose to play these turns rhythmically? how else could the notes be notated?

Comment: I voted to reopen, because the dup question is about a turn between _the same two pitches_, but this turn is between _two different pitches_. I assume the turn will be pitches above and below the second, target pitch, the `A`. But, that isn't completely clear. I think an answer making that clear would be helpful for the community.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Actually I would assume the opposite, "F E D# E"

Answer (score 1):

The difference between writing it above a note and after (between) the note is that in the "after" case, the principal note is played first. There is leeway in the exact execution, but two possibilities are notated below.

[image: Turn notations]

In the first, the principal note and the note above form a dotted rhythm on the first half of the beat with a triplet forming the second half. Alternatively, the first half of the beat can be the principal note and the second half containing the entire turn.

Another possibility, not notated, is to divide the beat into three parts: 1) the principal note, 2) a triplet of the upper neighbor, principal, and lower neighbor, and 3) the principal note.

In measure 10, Demus uses the second option, above. The principle note takes up half the time allotted to it, then the turn takes up the other half. The is typical.